# type mismatch Run time error 13, while Undoing Ctrl+z for multi deleted cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm learning VBA trying in my live Excel sheets.

I have VBA code, 1st got

> Runtime Error 13 type mismatch

while deleting multiple cells, with small work I'm not getting the error while deleting multiple cells, but when I do UNDO to the multi deleted cells, the same error occurs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 6 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Target.Cells(1).Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        If Len(Target.Offset(, -4)) = 0 Then
            Range("J" & ThisRow).Value = Time()
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Value = Date
            Range("AA" & ThisRow).Value = Environ("username")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this mean to work for only 1 cell at a time? You could always have a If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub  otherwise.

Comment: Yes GURU,Its working thanks for Assist

Comment: This also means it will only respond if you paste a single cell. And you cannot alter more than once cell at once and get the expected result. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: yes u r right,if i alter again then it giving that altered time and date which i dont want.

Comment: Explain more about desired result please? What do you mean by altered time and date?

Comment: The Excel share by 5 people.who ever enter data in c6,they get their Username,date,and current time,so if another person want to edit same cell,previous user data(Username,Time,Date) should not chage,that is the moto

Comment: You are doing your test on column F changing but you mention C6 as the target cell. Do you actually mean to monitor C6?

Comment: Yes QHarr,am testing in F only,Bymistake i mentioned C6,kindly ignore

Comment: I think TimWilliams's answer may be more what you are after if trying to handle multi-cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(6))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            If Len(c.Offset(0, -4).Value) = 0 Then
                With c.EntireRow
                    .Cells(1, "J").Value = Time()
                    .Cells(1, "B").Value = Date
                    .Cells(1, "AA").Value = Environ("username")
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: above code i have copy and paste in new sheet,it giving error "Run-time Error 1004"Application defined or object defined error debugging at "If Len(c.Offset(0, -4).Value) = 0 Then",kindly help

Comment: when i change Me.Coloumns(6) to Me.coloumns(2) ,it giving error "Run-time Error 1004"Application defined or object defined error debugging at "If Len(c.Offset(0, -4).Value) = 0 Then",kindly help

Comment: You cant offset 4 columns to the left from Col 2

Answer (score 0):

If only interested in producing a result for single cell changes (i.e. target is a single cell) then you can add:

```
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

Multi-cell changes will then not be responded to and you won't get the type mismatch error of `.Value` with multiple cells as this property belongs to a single cell range object.

This also means it will only respond if you paste a single cell. And you cannot alter more than once cell at once and get the expected result.

You have a second sheet (Sheet2) which acts as a store of which cells are populated. This is then checked to see if you should respond to the current event if Sheet1.

```
Option Explicit
Public monitorCell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim ThisRow
    If Target.Column = 6 Then 
        ThisRow = Target.Row

        If Not IsEmpty(monitorCell) Or Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        If Len(Target.Offset(, -4)) = 0 Then
            Range("J" & ThisRow) = Time()
            Range("B" & ThisRow) = Date
            Range("AA" & ThisRow) = Environ$("username")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Set monitorCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Target.Address)
End Sub
```